# Oracle Apex - URL link that passes values

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have been working on a simple survey app and what to send out emails inviting people to do the survey, the link includes the population of item on the home screen using the following notation :

```
https:// ... /apex/f?p=56773:1:::::P1_UNIQUE_CODE:A281Skh7
```

There is no authentication to fill in the survey other than this unique code. This works when I am already logged into apex as a dev but if I email it to someone else it immediately diverts and gets a session number and clears the P1_UNIQUE_CODE:A281Skh7 part that sets the value.

Is there a way to construct a apex URL that sets values when you are not already logged in?

**Note:** using Apex5

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You may want to consider adding an Application Alias and a Page Alias so that you're not hardcoding the IDs in your email links - e.g. `https://.../apex/f?p=MYAPP:HOME:::::P_UNIQUE_CODE:A281Skh7` (i.e. use an application-level attribute for the code as well).

Comment: I can you tell me why this is important? is it just so the app can be moved and the link still works?

Comment: Yes, that's all there is to it. I don't mind having page IDs within an application but I like to have the flexibility to redirect requests to a different page or a different application if those links are stored in old emails or other external web sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the page attribute **Authentication** to **Page Is Public**.